# After clearing magento 1.9.2 using sql i got error of getId()

Tags: magento-1.9, catalog

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function getId() on a non-object in /var/www/vhosts/pstest.de/amaya1.psweb.in/lib/Varien/Data/Tree/Dbp.php on line 331
```

I used some sql to truncate the product and category tables after clearing the database when i clicked on catalog > manage category it gives me above error.

Comment: run reindexing  first

Comment: After flushing the cache , error gone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As this problem is solved so i am posting this as answer. What i did

1. Clear Cache.
2. Run re-indexing  as @MineshPatel suggested by using putty or below php code.

   ```
    <?php
   require_once 'Mage.php';   // to get the direct access in any file
   $app = Mage::app('admin'); // work like super user by passing  admin 

   for ($indexer = 1; $indexer <= 9; $indexer++)
   {
        $reindexProcess = Mage::getModel('index/process')->load($indexer);
        $reindexProcess->reindexAll();
   }

   where $indexer ids are for
   1 = Product Attributes
   2 = Product Price
   3 = Catalog URL Rewrites
   4 = Product Flat Data
   5 = Category Flat Data
   6 = Category Products
   7 = Catalog Search Index
   8 = Stock Status
   9 = Tag Aggregation Data
   ```

I found this code on SE itself and i tried the above code it works.